# Create service in SF for non-SF resources to call

Tags: apex, api, integration

I am new to this so bear with me.

Ask: I am looking to write code/create a service in SF that I can provide another team outside of SF to call real-time in order to fetch information from two specific Salesforce custom objects. I would like to provide an endpoint/something easy for the other team to call. For security, wouldn't want it to be extremely hackable so should be mindful of security/likely needing authentication. The specific scenario is knowing when there has been changes on these SF custom object records.

Example: Object A and Object B have had updated records. The other team would like to be able to call an endpoint that will show this change or at least what the current data is so that they can use this information to update information on their Java-based application.

Is there standard SF documentation or examples online around the best way to approach that?

thanks!

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. There are a lot of ways to accomplish this task; the devil's in the details, as they say. Should they need authentication? Any security concerns? Etc. The more descriptive you are, the more descriptive we'll be. You can [edit] your question to add detail.

Comment: @sfdcfox thank you. Part of this learning experience for me is knowing the right description to provide. I added a tiny bit more in the description. for security, i think that it shouldn't be hackable and likely needing authentication because this isn't information i wouldn't want leaked to just anyone.

Comment: Take a look at https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/data-integration for an overview of the options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce already provides a SOAP-based [Replication API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/calls_for_data_replication.htm) as well as the REST-based [sObject Get Updated](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_getupdated.htm) and [sObject Get Deleted](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_getdeleted.htm). This is probably the best option for  near real-time updates, as it even tells you when the next replication window should be set to. You can authenticate to Salesforce through various methods, such as [JWT](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&language=en_US&type=5), [OAuth](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&language=en_US&type=5), and so on. Of course, there's lots of other ways to get this data, too, but I think this would probably be the easiest to implement. Other options might be available as well, such as using [Outbound Messages](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.workflow_managing_outbound_messages.htm&type=5), [Change Data Capture](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_intro.htm), and so on, which provides event-based notifications rather than having a polling loop.